# How to convert JSON response to String?

Tags: android, json, gson

I am working on an app and briefly my app gets information from user and list the workers in the company by using web service. I added Gson library to Android Studio but it does not working. I google the issue and tried everything that may be solution. However, I tried do it without Gson library but I do not knot how to do it. Here is the part of my code that makes me confused:

```
HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(SERVICE_URL);
        try {
            androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_GONDER_ACTION, envelope);

            if (envelope.bodyIn instanceof SoapObject) {

                SoapObject soapObject = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;
                Result gonderResult = Gson().fromJson(soapObject.getProperty(0), Result.class);
                return gonderResult.Result;


            } else if (envelope.bodyIn instanceof SoapFault) {

                SoapFault soapFault = (SoapFault) envelope.bodyIn;
                throw new Exception(soapFault.getMessage());
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return "error";
        }
```

My question is that Android studio doesn't sense the Gson() written above. What else can I do? How do I parse the JSON response without using Gson library?

Comment: >Android studio doesn't sense the Gson()< What does this mean? did you not import the library? What is the response you are getting, what are you expecting?

Comment: I import this library -> import com.google.gson.*; but "Gson" is still red. My app will do that : A user will enter the information (ex: personName,personSite) and once button is clicked persons who are working at the same site of company and have the same names should be list. @Lady_A

Comment: Did you try new Gson()

Comment: Yes, it doesn't make a difference :( @SrikarReddy

Comment: See my answer it will make difference . It will make the red "Gson" go from `import com.google.gson.*`

Answer (score 0):

Put `compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'` or a later version as dependency to your build.gradle build file. Then your android studio will recognize gson.

Comment: It gives the error message "Could not find method dependency() for arguments [build_3nvi1jir9vo79o48o9v6r87ou$_run_closure1@2c395e2e] on project ':gson-2.8.2-javadoc' of type org.gradle.api.Project." @KoustuvGanguly

Comment: try the latest version of gson

Answer (score 0):

According to [the GitHub page](https://github.com/google/gson) you should do something along the lines of:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
}
```

to use GSON in Android. They also list tutorials which may be of use to you. Honestly it just sounds like you haven't got the dependency set up.